# Meaning of the colormap._lut list in matplotlib.color

Tags: matplotlib, color-mapping

If I understood well, a colormap is an object which fixes a map from a set of numbers to colors.This map can be summarized by using the "lut". To see the "lut" associated to a cmap
you have to call `cmap._init()`, then you can see the `cmap._lut` What does it mean? Isn't the Lut an attribute of any cmap object? What does precisely do the `._init()`?.
The Lut is made up of N+3 rows and 4 columns where N is the number of colours of the cmap.
The first N rows are the RGBA representation of the corresponding colours. What are the last
three rows? What do they represent?

I hope my questions are not too stupid. Thanks!

Comment: If you found the answer, you should answer (and accept that answer) your own question instead of editing the question.

Comment: Ok, I added it as an answer. Sorry for the mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer for the last question. The last three rows are the colours for data low and high out-of-range values and for masked values.